# Adding Comment to Fortify Issue via REST API results in Content Encoding Error

Tags: c#, .net, rest, fortify

I'm trying to add a comment to an issue inside Fortify.  When I POST what I think is the correct JSON, I receive the response "{"message":"Content was incorrectly formatted (expected application/json; charset=utf-8).","responseCode":400,"errorCode":-20209}"

However, if I use Fiddler to examine the message I'm POSTing and receiving the appropriate headers appear to be in place.  What secondary issue could be causing this exception to be thrown?

Fortify v18.10.0187
.NET v4.6.2
Newtonsoft.Json v9.0.0

```
 public static string PostCommentIssue(FortifyComment fc)
 {
      var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fc);
      var postUri = String.Format(Configuration.FortifyCommentsUri, fc.data.issueId);
      return WebServiceHelper.PostMessage(postUri, content);
 }

 public static string PostMessage(string url, string content)
 {
      HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
      requestMessage.Headers.Add("Authorization", Configuration.FortifyAuthorization.ToHeader());
      requestMessage.Content = new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, JsonMediaTypeFormatter.DefaultMediaType.MediaType);

      HttpResponseMessage hrm = HttpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage).Result;
      hrm.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
      HttpContent hc = hrm.Content;

      return hc.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
 }
```

FortifyComment is just an object with the basic elements of a comment in it.  It's based on the Fortify response given on a query (thus the inner data element).

Using

```
 FortifyComment fc = new FortifyComment();
 fc.data.issueId = defect.id;
 fc.data.comment = String.Format("TFS #{0}.", tfsNumber);
 FortifyHelper.PostCommentIssue(fc);
```

I receive the 400 error.  Screenshot of Fiddler intercept:
[image: Fiddler capture 1][image: Fiddler capture 2 (request body)]